# Find the second biggest prime number of a group of numbers

Tags: primes

This is my first time I post a question on Stackoverflow, so my words or sentences might not be very appropriate, sorry for my poor English.

My homework demand is finding the second biggest prime number of a group of numbers A with the elements A1, A2, ..., An and the conditions are: 0 <= Ai <= 10^9 and 0 <= n <= 10^6. The time limit is 1 sec.

I've tried to use eratosthenes sieve or checking manually a number by divide it in a range from 2 to sqrt(Ai) but both of them cannot handle when it comes to 10^9. I hope someone can give me an instruction to solve this problem, thank you.^

Comment: Why doesn't the Sieve of Eratosthenes work for you? The storage needs are large but should work using 1 byte per sieve element, but if you don't have enough storage then 1 bit per sieve element is possible, with more work to test, set, and clear these entries. And you need only sieve out primes <= 10**4.5.

Comment: My teacher said that Eratosthenes worked well with max value up to 10^7 because it could lead to TLE if the max one is over that limit, so i got rid of using that solution. And as you said, i can use it without any problems, right ?

Comment: Search for "offset sieve" in my answers. [Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+offset+sieve). I suspect your A1 value is also given to you in the task, so the upper segment would start from it.